# Numerov method for Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

While learning about numerical methods for solving the Schrödinger equation I came across [Numerov's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov%27s_method).

I want to get the solution for the harmonic oscillator by alreading giving the eigenvalues. The algorithm requires that I know two initial values of $\psi$ while I only know that $\psi$ must vanish at thr boundary. How are those initial values found? Also it would be great if someone could refer me to some resources for this method.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting your grid points by $x_1, x_2, ... x_N$ it is correct that you need the values of $\Psi(x_1)$ and $\Psi(x_2)$ to execute Numerov's algorithm. As you write in your post, $\Psi(x_1)$ is given by the boundary condition. For $\Psi(x_2)$ you can take any non zero value you like, as the correct value can always be computed by normalizing $\Psi$ once you have obtained it at all grid points.

Comment: That is not entirely correct.  The sign of $\Psi(x_2)$ determines the parity of the wavefunction and cannot be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: I think it is indeed correct. Multiplying $\Psi(x)$ by a constant does not change its parity and you can therefore just multiply it by $-1$ if you like.